# Any benefit to decoupling controllers from services that interact with the server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, service, structure

In Angular.js, I was wondering if there's any sort of decoupling benefit to having an additional interface between a controller and a service that makes requests to the server.

I've been doing this lately and I can't really tell if it's totally pointless to have this extra hop and if this is really just the same handshake only with an extra hand in the middle, etc.

So I have a controller, then a service injected into that controller. This service is injected with the actual "server-request service" and it reports back to the controller with a callback or pub/sub.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: There is benefit if your Model (data entities) is considerably different than how you want your ViewModel to be. This layer can do the conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say it depends on the main purpose of your Service.
Let me get it right essentially you have this:

```
Controller A
|
|--> Service Main
   |
   |--> Service Ajax
```

So let's say the main service is full of business logic, and this depends on ajax queries. But the ajax queries itself may have varying implementations based on each customer. In this case your decoupling scenario may make it easier to exchange them more quickly. Besides that any data-transformation, like merging multiple requests from different sources etc. could be done here and your main Controller just maintains logic tied to your app. But really at this point it seems more like a personal flavor instead of a best-advice-rule.

What I would thou strongly advise is to minimize usage of pub/sub (in case you used $broadcast/$emit) since those introduce a lot of overhead, especially in bigger applications. Instead of that try to return a promise from the ajax-query all the way down to the controller.

Comment: There's actually no business logic going on in the Interface Service (half of what led me to this post). That's it with the visual only each controller has it's own, unique Interface Service, only there to avoid directly injecting the single AJAX Service into each controller, which they all rely on.

So there's this extra hop to avoid the direct injection. What I don't understand is whether or not this is actually creating the benefits of a decoupled entity. Seems like the controllers are only somewhat isolated from other concerns.

And no Angular pub/sub. I'm using a Mediator Pattern Service.

Comment: So the data from the server is returned to the interface. Callback to controller. No pub/sub there.